# Visual Studio - Connecting to a Mac Server

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I'm trying my hand at cross-platform development with Visual Studio, and I'm trying to follow a [video tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuzyVor2OvU).  I'm running VS2105 on my Win10 computer.  I tried to open the `Main.storyboard` file in my iOS project and this window appears:

[image: Apparently, I should click the link]

I take the only path available, and I'm greeted with this dialog:

[image: Wow... do I have a virtual Mac I didn't know about?]

...who wouldn't click "Connect", right?  Well that gets me here:

[image: where did this mystery Mac come from?]

...so here I am, wondering what to do next.  It looks like Visual Studio *sees* a Mac, but I've got no idea where it got that impression - I haven't an Apple product of any kind in my home.  I thought that *maybe* there was a virtual Mac running in Hyper-V somehow when this project was created, but come on - Apple ain't gonna go for that.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: You need a Mac for any iOS development.  If you don't have a Mac, click Cancel.  I'm not sure why it *thinks* you have a Mac on your network - it may just be looking for an open ssh port

Comment: Check out this article https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it found a Mac somewhere on the network. You need to enable Remote Login, login to the mac, then put in the username and password for the logged in user.

If this is not your mac, then ignore it. You HAVE to have a mac for ios development. If you want to do iOS, then you need to get one.